# Como ejecutar un proceso todos los días a una misma hora en Windows form?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**

Buenas noches..

Estoy haciendo un rpa con windows form en c# este va conectado a un  servicio que se ejecuta cuando se da a iniciar al proceso, el caso es que este proceso tiene que ejecutarse diariamente a una hora en especifico y de ahi no volver a ejecutarse hasta el otro día a esa misma hora, yo estoy ocupando el timer con un intervalo de tiempo, le doy para que inicie a las 8 pm y de ahi en 7 horas vuelve a ejecutar pero como no es la hora que le di pues no va a ejecutar el proceso hasta que llegue la hora. Esto lo plantee porque también tengo que realizar en el proceso que jale el servicio dándole un rango de fechas entonces no debe repetirse el que debe realizarse diario aunque elijan otras fechas.

El asunto son dos cosas una se me solicito que mi botón de detener , me deje como dice detener el proceso cuando yo por X razón me equivoque, debido a que una vez iniciando el proceso este bloquea todo el formulario hasta que termine no me deja volver a seleccionar el botón. Y dos pues yo les menciono que debo ejecutarlo diariamente a una hora y ocupe el intervalo no se si haya otra forma en que pueda realizar esto para que sea la situación que sea este se ejecute a esa hora  obvio sin afectar el segundo proceso que es elegir fechas de una forma mas fácil.

De antemano gracias espero haberme dado a entender.Aclaro no puedo ocupar algo diferente al formulario de windows forms y realmente no entiendo mucho porque soy nueva en esta herramienta.

**

```
 private void timerProceso_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                BarraProgreso.Visible = false;
                BarraProgreso.Value = 0;
                txtMensaje.Text = "";
    
                DateTime ldatFechaActual = DateTime.Now;
                string lstrFechaHoraActual = Convert.ToDateTime(ldatFechaActual).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd H:mm");
                scheduleTimer = DateTime.Today.AddHours(20).AddMinutes(10);
                Convert.ToDateTime(scheduleTimer).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd H:mm");
    
                string dirMensajes = "C:\\temp";
                string fileName = $"\\LogMensajes{ldatFechaActual.ToString("ddMMyyyy")}.txt";
               
                try
                {
                    timerProceso.Interval = 120000;
                    this.BarraProgreso.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                    BarraProgreso.Maximum = 100;
                    BarraProgreso.Step = 25;
                    string lstrFechaInicio = dateFechaFin.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    string lstrFechaActual = ldatFechaActual.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    
                    if (lstrFechaInicio != lstrFechaActual)
                    {
                        DateTime ldatFechaInicio = dateFechaInicio.Value;
                        DateTime ldatFechaFin = dateFechaFin.Value;
    
                        timerProceso.Enabled = false;
                        DialogResult dresulConfirmacion = MessageBox.Show("Seguro que desea iniciar?", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        if (dresulConfirmacion == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            BarraProgreso.Visible = true;
                            BarraProgreso.Value = 25;
                            BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                            txtProceso.Visible = true;
    
                            if (dateFechaFin.Value.Date < ldatFechaActual || lstrFechaInicio != lstrFechaActual)
                            {
                                //Inserción de documentos por rangos
                                string lstrFechaRegistro1 = ldatFechaInicio.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                                string lstrFechaRegistro2 = ldatFechaFin.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    
                                BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                                using (WSDocumento.ServiceClient wsRPA = new WSDocumento.ServiceClient())
                                {
                                    BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                                    string lstr = wsRPA.plistObtenerGuias(lstrFechaRegistro1, lstrFechaRegistro2);
    
                                    int columnas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Add();
                                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[0].Value = ldatFechaActual.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[1].Value = ldatFechaInicio.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + ldatFechaFin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[2].Value = lstr.ToString();
    
                                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
                                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
                                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
    
                                    dateFechaInicio.Value = DateTime.Now;
                                    BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
    
                                    if (Directory.Exists(dirMensajes))
                                    {
                                        using (var logMensajes = new StreamWriter(dirMensajes + fileName, true))
                                        {
                                            var numFilas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Count;
                                            int contador = 1;
                                            
                                            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gdvRegistros.Rows)
                                            {
                                                if (numFilas == contador)
                                                {
                                                    logMensajes.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value} | {row.Cells[1].Value} | {row.Cells[2].Value}");
    
                                                    string lstrFechasRegistradas = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                                    string lstrExcepciones = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                                    string lstrExcepciones = wsRPA.pstringInsertaExcepciones(lstrFechasRegistradas, lstrExcepciones);
                                                }
                                                contador++;
                                            }
                                        }
    
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirMensajes);
    
                                        using (var logMensajes = new StreamWriter(dirMensajes + fileName, true))
                                        {
                                            var numFilas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Count;
                                            int contador = 1;
                                            
                                            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gdvRegistros.Rows)
                                            {
                                                if (numFilas == contador)
                                                {
                                                    logMensajes.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value} | {row.Cells[1].Value} | {row.Cells[2].Value}");
    
                                                    string lstrFechasRegistradas = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                                    string lstrExcepciones = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                                    string lstrExcepciones = wsRPA.pstringInsertaExcepciones(lstrFechasRegistradas, lstrExcepciones);
                                                }
                                                contador++;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                                }
                            }
    
                            timerProceso.Enabled = false;
                            
                            //timerProceso.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        if (dresulConfirmacion == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                            BarraProgreso.Value = 25;
                            timerProceso.Stop();
                            BarraProgreso.Value = 100;
                            dateFechaInicio.Value = DateTime.Now;
                            dateFechaFin.Value = DateTime.Now;
                            txtMensaje.Text = "Proceso terminado.";
                            this.BarraProgreso.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                        }
    
                    }
    
                    else
                    {
                        if (scheduleTimer < ldatFechaActual)
                        {
                            timerProceso.Interval = 21600000; //6 horas         //3600000;   // 1 hora
                            //timerProceso.Interval = 86400000;  // 24 horas
    
                            BarraProgreso.Visible = true;
                            BarraProgreso.Value = 25;
                            txtProceso.Visible = true;
                            BarraProgreso.Visible = true;
                            BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                            BarraProgreso.Value = 25;
                            
                            //Inserción de documentos por día
                            //bg.RunWorkerAsync();
                            DateTime ldatFechaAnterior = ldatFechaActual.AddDays(-1);
                            //15/12/08 00:00:00
                            string lstrFechaRegistro1 = ldatFechaAnterior.ToString("20081215");
                            string lstrFechaRegistro2 = ldatFechaAnterior.ToString("20081225");
                            
                            BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                            using (WSDocumento.ServiceClient wsRPA = new WSDocumento.ServiceClient())
                            {
                                this.BarraProgreso.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                                
                                BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                                string lstr = wsRPA.plistObtenerGuiasInvesdoc(lstrFechaRegistro1, lstrFechaRegistro2);
                                
                                int columnas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Add();
                                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[0].Value = ldatFechaActual.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[1].Value = ldatFechaAnterior.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[2].Value = lstr.ToString();
    
                                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
                                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
                                gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
    
                                dateFechaInicio.Value = DateTime.Now;
    
                                BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                                if (Directory.Exists(dirMensajes))
                                {
                                    using (var logMensajes = new StreamWriter(dirMensajes + fileName, true))
                                    {
                                        var numFilas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Count;
                                        int contador = 1;
                                        
                                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gdvRegistros.Rows)
                                        {
                                            if (numFilas == contador)
                                            {
                                                logMensajes.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value} | {row.Cells[1].Value} | {row.Cells[2].Value}");
    
                                                string lstrFechasRegistradas = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                                string lstrExcepciones = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                                string lstrExcepciones = wsRPA.pstringInsertaExcepciones(lstrFechasRegistradas, lstrExcepciones);
                                            }
                                            contador++;
                                        }
    
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirMensajes);
    
                                    using (var logMensajes = new StreamWriter(dirMensajes + fileName, true))
                                    {
                                        var numFilas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Count;
                                        int contador = 1;
    
    
                                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gdvRegistros.Rows)
                                        {
                                            if (numFilas == contador)
                                            {
                                                logMensajes.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value} | {row.Cells[1].Value} | {row.Cells[2].Value}");
    
                                                string lstrFechasRegistradas = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                                string lstrExcepciones = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    
                                                string lstrExcepciones = wsRPA.pstringInsertaExcepciones(lstrFechasRegistradas, lstrExcepciones);
                                            }
                                            contador++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
    
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    txtProceso.Text = "";
                    BarraProgreso.Value = 100;
                    txtMensaje.Text = "Proceso terminado.";
                    timerProceso.Enabled = false;
                    MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message.ToString()}.", "Error de ingreso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                    int columnas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Add();
                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[0].Value = ldatFechaActual.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[1].Value = "-";
                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[2].Value = ex.Message.ToString();
    
                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[0].ReadOnly = true;
                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
                    gdvRegistros.Rows[columnas].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
    
                    if (Directory.Exists(dirMensajes))
                    {
                        using (var logMensajes = new StreamWriter(dirMensajes + fileName, true))
                        {
                            var numFilas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Count;
                            int contador = 1;
    
                            using (WSDocumento.ServiceClient wsRPA = new WSDocumento.ServiceClient())
                            {
                                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gdvRegistros.Rows)
                                {
                                    if (numFilas == contador)
                                    {
                                        logMensajes.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value} | {row.Cells[1].Value} | {row.Cells[2].Value}");
    
                                        string lstrFechasRegistradas = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                        string lstrExcepciones = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                        string lstrExcepciones = wsRPA.pstringInsertaExcepciones(lstrFechasRegistradas, lstrExcepciones);
                                    }
                                    contador++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirMensajes);
    
                        using (var logMensajes = new StreamWriter(dirMensajes + fileName, true))
                        {
                            var numFilas = gdvRegistros.Rows.Count;
                            int contador = 1;
    
                            using (WSDocumento.ServiceClient wsRPA = new WSDocumento.ServiceClient())
                            {
                                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gdvRegistros.Rows)
                                {
                                    if (numFilas == contador)
                                    {
                                        logMensajes.WriteLine($"{row.Cells[0].Value} | {row.Cells[1].Value} | {row.Cells[2].Value}");
    
                                        string lstrFechasRegistradas = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                                        string lstrExcepciones = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                                        string lstrExcepciones = wsRPA.pstringInsertaExcepciones(lstrFechasRegistradas, lstrExcepciones);
                                    }
                                    contador++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    timerProceso.Enabled = false;
                }
                
                BarraProgreso.PerformStep();
                if (BarraProgreso.Value == 100)
                {
                    txtProceso.Text = "";
                    txtMensaje.Text = "Proceso terminado.";
                    this.BarraProgreso.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    dateFechaFin.ResetText();
                }
                timerProceso.Start();
    
            }
```

Comment: Supongo que querrás crear una tarea del programador de tareas.

Comment: tarea disculpa no te entiendo?

Comment: ¿Estás en Windows? Entonces abre el programador de tareas y crea una. O la aplicación está ejecutandose permanentemente y solo quieres que haga algo en específico a determinada hora?

Comment: esque mi formulario de windows tiene dos procesos uno se debe ejecutar diario y otro si el usuario quiere ejecutarlo. ese programador de tareas como es disculpe?

Comment: Busca en Windows "Programador de tareas". Este programa viene con Windows y permite justamente hacer lo que tú quieres. Tiene muchas configuraciones, por lo que lo mejor es que busques una guía.